# combo box not refreshing with new data

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an observable collection property in the code behind

```
 public ObservableCollection<ChildGroupComboBoxBO> ChildGroupOC {
      get 
      { return childGroupOC;}
      set                 
      {
         childGroupOC = value;               
      }
 }
```

This collection is bound to a combobox in the xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChildGroupOC}" DisplayMemberPath="groupName" />
```

When I read load the page, I read data from the database, load up the observable collection and it binds to the combo box just fine.  However, when I add a record to the database, and use the exact same routine to load the combo box again, the new record does not show up in the list even though I can see it added to the collection in memeory.  How do I get the combo box to refresh it's list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not recreate the observable collection. Clear its values and AddRange all values again. It would be better to simply add the one value that you store to your DB into your existing.

The binding expression binds to the old instance and you set `ChildGroupOC = new ObservableCollection(...)` - the binding still tracks the old instance.

Comment: I need the id of the value that was inserted into the database, which is an identity field.  Should i query for the max value and then manually add that to the observable collection?  It seems messy.

Comment: @nikotromus depending on how much work is done in `ChildGroupComboBoxBO` I would query for the exact Item I inserted (by its other value fields) - or use an insert procedure that returns me the ID or ask the DBContext for all IDs and see which ID is not yet in my observable or ... several possibilities

Comment: It makes sense.  It just seems weird that I can problematically instantiate a new object and it doesn't pickup the change.  Now that I know how it works, I can work with it .  Thanks Patrick.